# javascript loop form values by name then element id

Tags: javascript, forms

I have loop going though form values, it is working fine throwing out the values based on the input name. But I would also like to be able to target by specific element id.

This is an example form:

```
_inputFields: function() {
    var rows = [];
    for(var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
      var placeHolder = 'Intro text line ' + i;
      var inputID = 'inputIntroText ' + i;
      rows.push(<input type="text" className="form-control input-size-lg" name="formInput" id="inputText" placeholder={placeHolder}/>);
      rows.push(<input type="text" className="form-control input-size-lg" name="formInput" id="inputTime" placeholder={placeHolder}/>);
    }
```

So I can loop through and grab everything by name i.e. 'formInput' but how can I then grab `formInput[inputText]` and `formInput[inputTime]`?

This is my current loop through the values :

```
// gather form input
var elem = document.getElementsByName('formInput');
console.log(elem);

// Build the object
var obj = {
    "DataObject": {
        "user": {
            "-name": "username"
        },
        "contentFile": {
            "-filename": "Breaking_News",
            "lock": {
                "-fileIsBeingEdited": "false"
            },
            "content": {
                "line": []
            }
        }
    }
};

var line = obj.DataObject.contentFile.content.line;
for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    if (elem[i].value != '') {
        line.push({
            "-index": i,
            "-text": elem[i]['inputText'].value,
            "-time": elem[i]['inputTime'].value
        });
    }
};
```

If I try:

```
"-text": elem[i]['inputText'].value,
"-time": elem[i]['inputTime'].value
```

I get the error: `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Just use `"-text": elem[i].id`

Comment: Your logic is wrong. when you do `document.getElementsByName('formInput');`, you get two input elements with same name and different ids. Why do you later want to access the two in one iteration? The interpreter is correct to tell you `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`, since the indices you are trying to access, don't exist in you elems array

Answer (score 1):

This errors because `elem[i]['inputText']` is `undefined`.  This is because you are trying to lookup the `inputText` property of the element, which doesn't exist.

`elem` is an array, so I'd recommend using something like [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
"-text": elem.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id === 'inputText';
})[0].value;
```

Also, you should remove the for loop or you will get a duplicate line.

```
function getElementById(elems, id){
    return elems.filter(function(item) {
        return item.id === id;
    })[0];
}

var line = obj.DataObject.contentFile.content.line;
line.push({
    "-text": getElementById(elem, 'inputText').value,
    "-time": getElementById(elem, 'inputTime').value
});
```

Here's an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ku7yscmk/1/).

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, when trying to run your code (without the for loop) I get the error 'elem' is not defined on this line: "-text": getElementById(elem, 'inputText').value,

Comment: @chinds I've added an example jsfiddle to my answer.  The values are empty because it's running before the inputs can be set, but it doesn't error.

Comment: tahnks and I have just seen my error :/ I accidentally deleted the first line that was declaring elem. Thanks again.

Comment: ok so I have this working, but obviously it is not looping over the entire form, I have tried putting in a loop to go over each input field but i can't get it to work, there are 10 text input fields and 10 time input fields to the form.

Comment: @chinds I've updated the jsfiddle with an example that loops through three sets of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `elem[i].id`:

```
 var line = obj.DataObject.contentFile.content.line;
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    if (elem[i].value != '') {
         line.push({
        "-index": i,
        "-text": elem[i].id
       // Since you are looping through the inputs, you will get the `inputTime` in the 2nd iteration.
    });
   }
};
```